# Virtual Host ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: apache, google-chrome, xampp, windows-8.1, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a VirtualHost for laravel in apache on XAMPP.
I can access through Firefox, but if I type www.laravel.dev on Chrome I get this error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". Then, I tried to set it as "www.laravel.local" but it doesn't work either.

I followed this answer [Google Chrome virtual hosts not working with ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477552/google-chrome-virtual-hosts-not-working-with-err-name-not-resolved-error-after-u) and when I flush it keeps on saying:

> www.laravel.local IPV4    error: -105 (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) 2015-06-23
>   16:53:09.090 [Expired]

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public/"
   ServerName laravel.local
   ServerAlias www.laravel.local
</VirtualHost>
```

And the /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 www.laravel.local
```

Thank you for your time.